# Indentation of TypeScript types in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, types, webstorm

I want indentation of the parentheses at the end to be like this:

```
type MyType= (
     Foo |
     Abc |
     MoreStuff
);
```

But instead it's like this:

```
type MyType= (
    Foo |
    Abc |
    MoreStuff
    );
```

Is there any rule in WebStorm to fix this? I tried many things under `Code Style > TypeScript`, but nothing works.

Comment: there are no options for this; if you miss it, please feel free to file a feature request to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: @lena but is there any workaround so that when I reformat the code, the parentheses for type declarations stay as they are? Like any possible configuration that makes it ignore types while reformatting?

Comment: I can only suggest excluding these fragments from formatting - this can be done by surrounding the regions you don't like to be touched by formatter with the formatter markers: `//@formatter:off
your code here
//@formatter:on`. But you need to make sure to enable these markers in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style**, **Formatter Control/Enable formatter markers in comments**